# Jacobson Radical of the Tensor Product of Fields

Tags: field-theory, tensor-products

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, and take field extensions $K, L$ of $k$. The $k$-algebra $K \otimes_k L$ is a domain, and in particular it is a reduced. I am wondering if the Jacobson radical $\text{Jac}(K \otimes_k L)$ is $0$. If it isn't , then what conditions could be supplied so that it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that $\operatorname{Jac}(K\otimes_k L)=0$. The proof is not terrible, but its more than a few lines.

It looks like the first proof was by John Lawrence in 1989. I couldn't find a free PDF but it is available [here](https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/42/1/203/1544807?redirectedFrom=PDF). I found a shorter proof [here](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869391901493/1-s2.0-0021869391901493-main.pdf?_tid=2f82d1f2-efe2-411c-a21b-5d6a069978d5&acdnat=1531099336_e7312b0c87abbbbb35c8467ecf382bc7) from the same year (Theorem 2.4).

Answer (score 0):

If you suppose $K$ and $L$ are finitely generated $k$-algebras then $K \otimes_k L$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra, and you have $\sqrt 0 = \textrm{Jac}(K \otimes_k L)$ by the Nullstellensatz. Since you already know your algebra is reduced, it follows $ \textrm{Jac}(K \otimes_k L) = 0$.

Observation: I'm using that $\sqrt I = \cap m$ where $m$ is maximal ideal containing $I$.